# DELETE using a subquery in MySQL

Tags: mysql, subquery, sql-delete

I'd like to convert the following

```
SELECT * `members` m
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT s.mid
   FROM   memberships s 
   WHERE  s.mid = m.id);
```

to the equivalent delete statement. However, the code below doesn't work:

```
DELETE FROM `members` m
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT s.mid
   FROM   memberships s 
   WHERE  s.mid = m.id);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the multiple-table `DELETE` syntax to perform an outer join between the tables:

```
DELETE FROM members
USING members LEFT JOIN memberships ON memberships.mid = members.id
WHERE memberships.mid IS NULL
```